# How to dynamically add to a nested element in a JSON object in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, json

I want a json object which is equivalent to

```
var data = {"nodes":"var postLoadData = {\n nodes:{408868239:{'tipo':'clase','shape':'dot','label':'clase2'},843594076:{'tipo':'clase','shape':'dot','label':'ESTADIA'}},edges:{\n 2:{408868239:{},843594076:{}}}};\n \n sys.graft(postLoadData);"}
```

i have done like this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("nodes", "var postLoadData = {\n nodes:{408868239:{'tipo':'clase','shape':'dot','label':'clase2'},843594076:{'tipo':'clase','shape':'dot','label':'ESTADIA'}}," +
                "edges:{\n 2:{408868239:{},843594076:{}}}};\n \n sys.graft(postLoadData);");
```

i need to add edges and nodes dynamically to this json object. how to do that.

Comment: Do you want to modify JSON in Java or Javascript?

Comment: The data object will syntactically valid JSON, doesn't really lend itself to dynamically adding much of anything. You might want to consider restructuring your format.

Comment: Am I reading this wrong, or are you intentionally putting a var declaration inside a JSON object?

Comment: yes. i am sending this to java script.

Comment: JSON != JavaScript. JSON data is not a JavaScript program. It's just a data structure.

Comment: @RameshK The value you're adding is a `String` of JavaScript code. You won't be able to use this as a JSON object to "*add edges and nodes dynamically*."

Comment: @JonathanLonowski can you suggest me how to create a dynamic JSON java object for the data?

Comment: It's not JSON if it starts with anything other than `{`.

Comment: @ErikE Valid JSON is any "*value*" [defined in the spec](http://json.org/) -- that's not just "*object*."

Comment: @JonathanLonowski My apologies. I should have included arrays and scalars. It is clearly stated at [json.org](http://www.json.org/). In any case, the point was that you can't have procedural statements or expressions. Just values or array & object literal notation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the API for [JSONObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) it defines the operations you will need. From what I can see you will need to manipulate the value for the key `nodes`.

I'm curious to see what your JS is going to look like given you have JS in your JSON. Are you planning on calling `exec`? I'd be very careful how you implement. JSON is used to exchange data what you are trying to do is exchange JS which is not what it's intended for, nor is it safe to do so.

Comment: at java script side am calling just eval(data.nodes)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have JSON, what you have in that string is this javascript code:

```
var postLoadData = {
    nodes: {
        408868239: {
            'tipo': 'clase',
            'shape': 'dot',
            'label': 'clase2'
        },
        843594076: {
            'tipo': 'clase',
            'shape': 'dot',
            'label': 'ESTADIA'
        }
    },
    edges: {
        2: {
            408868239: {},
            843594076: {}
        }
    }
};
sys.graft(postLoadData);
```

The closest valid JSON of that could be:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "408868239": {
            "tipo": "clase",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "clase2"
        },
        "843594076": {
            "tipo": "clase",
            "shape": "dot",
            "label": "ESTADIA"
        }
    },
    "edges": {
        "2": {
            "408868239": {},
            "843594076": {}
        }
    }
}
```

You could use the above JSON (not the javascript code) and then do this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( theJsonString );
```